# C# Thread runs out of memory with no exception (1000 Monkeys and Typewriters-like program)

Tags: c#, multithreading, out-of-memory

Edit: SOLVED using a Static Random class. Turns out Randoms aren't thread safe.

```
public static class StaticRandom
{
    static int seed = Environment.TickCount;

    static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> random =
        new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random(Interlocked.Increment(ref seed)));

    public static int Next(int min, int max)
    {
        return random.Value.Next(min, max);
    }
}
```

Relatively short program here and it's just something I'm writing for fun. The program works fine on the main thread, but when I multithreaded it, the threads seem to stop for no reason and upon research, it seems they run out of memory in the stack.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace MonkeysTypewriters
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Thread[] monkeys = new Thread[Environment.ProcessorCount];
        private static Random r = new Random();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] dictionary = ReadDictionary();
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < monkeys.Length; i++)
                {
                    monkeys[i] = new Thread(() => GetRandomWord(dictionary));
                }
                foreach (Thread monkey in monkeys)
                {
                    monkey.Start();
                }
                foreach (Thread monkey in monkeys)
                {
                    monkey.Join();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string[] ReadDictionary()
        {
            return File.ReadAllLines(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/WORDS.TXT");
        }

        private static string GenerateWord()
        {
            string word = "";
            char nextLetter = (char)r.Next(65, 91);
            while (nextLetter != '[')
            {
                word += nextLetter;
                nextLetter = (char)r.Next(65, 92);
            }
            return word;
        }

        private static bool ValidateWord(string word, string[] dictionary)
        {
            return Array.BinarySearch(dictionary, word) >= 0;
        }

        private static void GetRandomWord(string[] dictionary)
        {
            string word = "";
            while (!ValidateWord(word, dictionary))
            {
                word = GenerateWord();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
    }
}
```

it seems to run out of memory in GenerateWord. Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me why they run out of memory?

WORDS.TXT is a text file of a huge list of English words.

Comment: `WORDS.TXT is a text file of a huge list of English words.` can this be reason?

Comment: "it seems to run out of memory in GenerateWord" - how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Agree, while the code to generate words is inefficient memory wise, there is no reason the GC cannot clean them up, and definitely no recursion causing a StackOverflowException

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I was writing Console.WriteLine statements in various functions and it randomly stopped outputting text to the console in all but the while loop inside GenerateWord(), though it may be because I didn't let it run long enough to get to OOM. But that is the most taxing part of the program.

Comment: Could it be because my thread is static and the stack never gets dumped after it finishes executing? The threads will stop executing even on short words after a few iterations of the main outer loop.

Comment: Is it possible the problem may be related to access at the same memory address on ValidateWord? I guess, try to put a semaphore there just to see if the problem may be related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Random` class is not thread safe. It may break and return the same number on every call to `Next`, and this is likely what you're experiencing, so `GenerateWord` never returns a valid word. See the [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) docs, particularly the section on thread safety.

The best way around this is to give each thread it's own `Random` instance. An easy way to achieve this is to turn your `static Random` into a `static ThreadLocal<Random>`:

```
private static ThreadLocal<Random> r = new ThreadLocal<Random>(
    () => new Random()
);
```

Comment: I was about to say the same thing; I think this can be verified by how many words are written to the console. My guess is it will write only a few then it stops outputting to console.

Comment: Thanks I ended up creating a static Random class that worked. The solution above worked but it generated the same values.